# ProcessingJS fails to draw images produced by PImage.get

Tags: image, processing

Here is some code that works great in Java and Android modes but doesn't work in JavaScript mode.  It uses PImage.get to extract a new PImage that contains a subregion of the original image.  I can draw the original image and any sub images in Java and Android modes but in JavaScript mode drawing sub images fails.  Here is a very basic demo of the problem.  Substitute your own image file or just download a zip of the sketch from http://readyposition.com/subImageTest.zip.

```
// Declare 2 images
PImage fullImage, subImage;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480);

  // Load an image from a file
  fullImage = loadImage("smurf_sprite.png");

  // Load the upper left quarter of the original image into a new image
  subImage = fullImage.get(0, 0, fullImage.width / 4, fullImage.height / 4);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  imageMode(CENTER);

  // Draw the full image in the background
  image(fullImage, width / 2, height / 2);

  // Draw the sub image where the mouse is
  image(subImage, mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

I tried to keep it simple.  Let me know if you know how to make this work for JavaScript mode.

Thanks,

~chuck

Answer (score 2):

I should have realized that ProcessingJS.org has different content in their references than Processing.org.  If you look at http://processingjs.org/reference/loadImage_/ you can see that you need to include a directive like:

```
/* @pjs preload="yourimagename.jog, yourimagename2.png";  */
```

so that images are preloaded.  In my case, I believe I was copying the image subregions before the pixels were loaded.